# Sufficiency without second derivative test

Tags: optimization

Consider a function $\mathcal C^1 \ni f : \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R$. The following properties are given:
\begin{align}
&f(0) = 0,\\
&f(\infty) = -\infty,\\
&f'(\bar x) = 0,\\
&|\{x : f'(x) = 0\}| = 1.
\end{align}
Claim: There exists a unique global maximizer $x^*$ defined as
\begin{align}
x^* = 
\begin{cases}
0 \quad &\text{if } f(\bar x) < 0,\\
\bar x &\text{if } f(\bar x) \geq 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
I'm pretty sure the statement is correct, but would not know how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 0):

Let $q$ be such that $f(x) < -1$ if $x > q$. As continuous function on compact $[0, q]$, $f$ achieves global maximum in at least one point $x_0$ (and as this maximum is non-negative, it's also global maximum on $\mathbb R_+$). If for some $x_1 \neq x_0$ we have $f(x_0) = f(x_1)$, assuming wlog $x_0 < x_1$ we have $f'(x_1) = 0$ and also $f'(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (x_0, x_1)$ - so $f' = 0$ in at least two points. Thus $f$ has unique global maximizer.

If this maximizer isn't $0$, then $f'$ in it is $0$. So global maximizer is either $x$ such that $f'(x) = 0$ or $0$ - in whichever $f$ is greater. This is exactly your last expression.